# How to cut the vector into bins represented by their centres

Tags: r

I've got some vector. For the purpose of this example let's create a one from uniform distribution:

```
x <- runif(1000, 0, 1)
```

Now I'd like to split the vector into `n` bins (let's say 10). It's easy with `cut`:

```
cut(x, 10)
```

but I'd like bins to be represented by their centres, not ranges. I have tried the following:

```
tapply(x, cut(x, 10), mean)
```

But it returns a vecor of unique values and I want a vector of size `n` with each value assigned to their respective bin (as in `cut` output, but represented as centres). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want a vector of size n with each value assigned to their
>   respective bin  (as in cut output, but represented as centres)

You just need to change `tapply` to `ave`.

```
ave(x, cut(x, 10), FUN = mean)
```

(I'm assuming `n` means `length(x)` here, not `10` since `tapply` already gives you a vector of length 10.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to label the different bins with their means instead of their range. This can be done by simply calculating the means of the different values in each bin:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
    x = runif(1000, 0, 1),
    bin = cut(x, 10)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(bin) %>% 
  summarize(
    mean = mean(x)
  )
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    bin               mean
#>    <fct>            <dbl>
#>  1 (0.00124,0.102] 0.0514
#>  2 (0.102,0.201]   0.148 
#>  3 (0.201,0.301]   0.253 
#>  4 (0.301,0.4]     0.349 
#>  5 (0.4,0.5]       0.451 
#>  6 (0.5,0.6]       0.548 
#>  7 (0.6,0.699]     0.648 
#>  8 (0.699,0.799]   0.746 
#>  9 (0.799,0.898]   0.849 
#> 10 (0.898,0.999]   0.950
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It results in 10 observations, as with `cut`, but I want to have all 1000 observations. I could do a `left_join` to original `data.frame`, but here's the thing - I don't want to create a `data.frame` as there has to be simpler solution within base R.

Comment: just change summarize to mutate :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like below?

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(10000, 0, 1)

n <- 10
bin <- cut(x,seq(0,1,by = 1/n))
tapply(x, bin, mean)
```

such that

```
> tapply(x, bin, mean)
   (0,0.1]  (0.1,0.2]  (0.2,0.3]  (0.3,0.4] 
0.04969784 0.14970878 0.25173077 0.35135862 
 (0.4,0.5]  (0.5,0.6]  (0.6,0.7]  (0.7,0.8] 
0.44943688 0.54991184 0.65178575 0.75063907 
 (0.8,0.9]    (0.9,1] 
0.85072782 0.94989779
```